# webdriver did not get to the next code after the function "is.Displayed" return false

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scriot which check webelement if it is displayed or not, if it is true(diplayed).he get in in the "if block" and execute the code, if not displayed he jump to the "else" block to execute the rest.
But my problem he stops  after the function "is.Diplayed" return false,and get to the else block to search for another weblement.
Though I put the code in a try catch block, it didn't help...

here the code:

```
   try{ 

    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='contentButtonAction']")).isDisplayed())
    {
            System.out.println("  SetOffline Button Text is    :"+driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='contentButtonAction']")).getText());
            if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='contentButtonAction']")).getText().equals("Offline stellen"))
            assertTrue("Stauts ist immer offline",driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='contentButtonAction']")).getText().equals("Offline stellen"));
    }

    else
      { 
         System.out.println("  Online stellem Button Text hat :"+driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[9]/form/div[2]/div/button")).getText());
         String onlinestellen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[9]/form/div[2]/div/button")).getText();

        assertEquals("Online stellen", onlinestellen.equals("Online stellen"));
        }
  }

  catch(ElementNotFoundException e){}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok , what issue you are getting?

Comment: @Helping Hands thank you...I found the solution: I think "isDisPlayed" function did not work good for me, I use instead of a "isElementPresent(By by)" function, which work god for me.

Comment: i change the old method=>`(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='contentButtonAction']")).isDisplayed()` with this one=>`if (isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("button[class='contentButtonAction']")))` ,and it worked fine

Comment: here is the declaration of the methode: `private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }`

Comment: ok that great then..

Comment: @otmann If you found a solution to your problem, it is perfectly acceptable, and helpful to the community, to answer your own question. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer